# Rails 3 and jquery highligth

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I search on google jquery rails example and see code below:

```
$('#div-id').effect('highlight', {}, 3000)
```

for highlight element which has id "div-id". But I can highlight in my code, I check with firebug and receive message

```
$('#div-id').effect is not a function
```

Can you help me to highlight an element with jquery in rails 3?
Thank you

Update: Where can I place jQuery UI for my rails project?

Answer (score 2):

`.effect()` is a jQuery UI function, make sure you are including the JS (and probably CSS) file(s) before making a call to the `.effect()` function.

You can download jQuery UI here: http://jqueryui.com/download

Note that you will need to include jQuery UI's JS file after the jQuery Core JS file.

Comment: Thank you for response. So jquery default for rails 3.1.3 is only jquery core, right? I download jQuery UI from your link, this is zip file. In zip file there are css and js folder, what need I do then? Where need I place these file in my rails project?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [jquery-rails](https://github.com/indirect/jquery-rails) gem, you can include the jquery-ui library by adding it to the application's asset manifest file, app/assets/application.js :

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require_tree .
```

This provides the basic ui effects you'll need for highlight, blind, slide and so on.

Answer (score 0):

probably you have not included the highlight plugin `js` file, make sure that you include the `js` files in proper oreder that is first include the `jquery.js` and then the plugin `js` file